# Rewriting Swift 1 syntax to Swift 3 - "Type Any has no subscript value"

Tags: swift3, syntax, skylink

```
var peerIds = [String]()
var peersInfos: NSMutableDictionary!

self.peersInfos.addEntries(from: [peerId: ["videoView": NSNull(), "videoSize": NSNull(), "isAudioMuted": NSNull(), "isVideoMuted": NSNull()]])

let videoView = (self.peersInfos[peerId]?["videoView"])!
let videoSize = (self.peersInfos[peerId]?["videoSize"])!
let isAudioMuted = (self.peersInfos[peerId]?["isAudioMuted"])!
```

This is the syntax from an app that was written in Swift 1 and Xcode 8 has converted it into Swift 3 to this. It is throwing an error saying "type Any has no subscript value". I have no clue how to fix this, please help me!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all even if your issue has been solved you will get the famous *Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value* error because the mutable dictionary is declared but not initialized.

The error *type Any has no subscript value* occurs because the value of a dictionary is `Any` by default and the compiler needs to know the static type of all subscripted objects.

The dictionary `peersInfos` contains a nested dictionary so declare it as native Swift type

```
var peerIds = [String]()
var peersInfos = [String:[String:Any]]()
```

then you can write

```
self.peersInfos[peerId] = ["videoView": NSNull(), "videoSize": NSNull(), "isAudioMuted": NSNull(), "isVideoMuted": NSNull()]

if let info = self.peersInfos[peerId] {
    let videoView = info["videoView"]!
    let videoSize = info["videoSize"]!
    let isAudioMuted = info["isAudioMuted"]!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you may want to use a usual Swift dictionary in this case, you should change

```
var peersInfos: NSMutableDictionary!
```

to

```
var peersInfos: [String: Any]!
```